# Make link from text inside brackets using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to use PHP to transform a text from this format:

`foo [[http://www.google.com|This Link points to google]] foo`

to this

`foo <a href="http://www.google.com">This Link points to google</a> foo`

I've made this code:

```
function linkLine($line) {
    if (preg_match('#\[\[(.*?)\]\]#', $line, $match)) {
        $arr = explode("|", $match[1], 2);
        $link = "<a href=\"$arr[0]\">$arr[1]</a>";
        return str_replace($match[0], $link, $line);
    } else {
        return $line;
   }
}
```

But i know that's is not elegant, not robust and doesn't work if there is more than one occurrences in the same line.

How can I improve it using `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the same regex with a `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$re = '/\[\[(.*?)]]/';
$str = 'foo [[http://www.google.com|This Link points to google]] foo [[http://www.more.com|This Link points to more]]';
echo preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) { 
    $arr = explode("|", $m[1], 2);
    return '<a href="' . $arr[0] . '">'. $arr[1] . '</a>'; 
}, $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/0Xdtyq).

Result:

```
foo <a href="http://www.google.com">This Link points to google</a> foo <a href="http://www.more.com">This Link points to more</a>
```

If the strings inside `[[` and `]]` cannot have `[`, `]` and only have 1 `|`, you may also use

```
$re = '/\[\[([^][|]*?)\|([^][]*?)]]/';
```

See the following [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/mdfTyc):

```
$re = '/\[\[([^][|]*?)\|([^][]*?)]]/';
$str = 'foo [[http://www.google.com|This Link points to google]] foo [[http://www.more.com|This Link points to more]]';
echo preg_replace($re, '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think 'style' is low on the list of priorities when it comes to text manipulation with regex. Higher on that list, in my opinion, is first and foremost functionality: does it work? Great. Second is readability: can others understand what it's doing, and if there's an error/mistake, can they easily fix it?

That said, your motivation to improve it is valid as it fails one of your functional requirements, that is, if there are multiple occurrences in the same line.

So why not approach this problem step by step:

1) Replace the first occurrence of ' [[' with '

2) Replace the first occurrence of '|' that follows after '[[' with '">'.

(this is a tricky one, since it requires a decision on your part. For the following example, which of the two outcomes would you prefer?:

3) foo [[http://www.google.com|This Link points to]] google]] foo

I'm going to go with the first instance of ']] '. If you want to capture outer brackets, then you'll need to use lookaheads to check to make sure there are no more ']] ' before '[[ '.

Following the above steps, I came up with (in javascript, so I can show an example):

```js
let regex = /(.*)(\s\[\[)(http:\/\/[^|]+)(\|)((.*)(?=\b)(\]\]\s))(.*)/;

let result = "foo [[http://www.google.com|This Link points to google]] foo".replace(regex,'$1 <a href="$3"/>$6</a> $8');

let pathologicalDataResult = "foo [[http://ww[[w.google.co|m|This Link poi]]nts to google]] foo".replace(regex,'$1 <a href="$3"/>$6</a> $8');

console.log(result);
console.log(pathologicalDataResult);
```